# Keep "Desktop" at the top of the Quick Access list in the Windows Explorer

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer

I'm not quite sure how this happened, but in my Windows Explorer (Windows 10), the "Desktop" link seems to sink to the bottom of the Quick Access list (based on how frequently I use it) while "Documents," "Downloads," and "Pictures stay static at the top of the list. It's very annoying and a bit of an eyesore.

Somehow it disappeared from the list and I had to add it back manually, which is why I suspect it's doing this (maybe the IT department did something with the registry, who knows). In any case, I'm wondering how to keep "Desktop" at the top where it belongs (like on every other Windows 10 PC I've used). Thanks

[image]

------Edit--------
I dragged the Desktop back to the top as-per the comment, I noticed that while the static folders (Documents, Downloads, Pictures) are labeled as System Folders, Desktop isn't labeled as anything. I dragged it up from the "This PC" section of the sidebar to the top of Quick Access. It's up there now because I just did it, but it'll sink back down eventually.

[image]

Comment: If your local IT did something you will need to ask them. If the didn't, you can simply drag the Desktop item to the top. It'll stay there until you've pinned other things, at which time you'll drag it back. The Quick Launch allows normal drag-to-order like many lists in MS applications.

Comment: Did that, it's still sinking down unfortunately

Comment: Then you need to talk with your local IT.

Comment: Happens on my personal desktop. But not personal laptop. Desktop has Windows 10 Pro, maybe something to do with that.

Answer (score 0):

Is the Desktop a shortcut or did you drag it from "This Pc"? If you didn't, remove it and try right-clicking the one from "This Pc" and click "Pin To Quick access".

If it doesn't work, maybe the location is messed up, try checking the "This Pc" Desktop location:
Right-click Desktop>Properties>Location and Restore Default

It should be like this if you're not using Onedrive: C:\Users\username\Desktop

Comment: Yeah, it came from "This PC," but I did everything you said anyway and still no dice

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I figured it out. You must remove all the other items from quick access except the desktop.  Then re-pin them one by one and they will be placed after the desktop.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I fixed this on my machine by resetting the pinned items. [This](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/175936-how-reset-clear-quick-access-pinned-folders-windows-10-a.html) tutorial shows how. Basically, delete the file:

```
%AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\AutomaticDestinations\f01b4d95cf55d32a.automaticDestinations-ms
```

I deleted all files under AutomaticDestinations, but I think only the one above is necessary.